# Unir resultados en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, select, join

Quisiera saber cómo puedo hacer para unir los resultados de varios `selects` en una misma tabla temporal si fuera posible, o si hay otra forma de hacerlo.

Este es el código que tengo por el momento:

```
Declare @mod as int;
Declare modelos cursor for select mod_Id from dbo.MODELS;
Open modelos;
fetch next from modelos into @mod;
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    select b.brn_Name,count(@mod) from dbo.BRANCHES b, dbo.BrnHasMac bm, dbo.MACHINES m where b.brn_Id = bm.brn_Id and m.mac_Id = bm.mac_Id and m.mod_Id = @mod group by (b.brn_Name);
    FETCH NEXT FROM modelos into @mod;
END
Close modelos;
DeAllocate modelos
```

Actualmente estoy obteniendo los resultados de la siguiente manera:

```
+-----------+  
Branch1 30  
Branch2 40  
+-----------+  
Branch1 10  
Branch2 5  
+-----------+
```

Pero quisiera obtenerlos juntos de la siguiente manera:

```
+-------------+  
Branch1 30 10  
Branch2 40 5  
+-------------+
```

Comment: Lo que estás pidiendo es un tipo de PIVOT. Normalmente, para obtener una columna por `mod_id`, necesitas saber de antemano los diferentes posibles valores para `mod_id`. ¿Es ese tu caso? ¿O pueden variar los valores posibles para `mod_id` en la tabla `dbo.MODELS`?

Comment: Qué versión de SQL Server estás usando?

Comment: Si, los valores si pueden variar, me refiero a variar en el sentido de que puedo agregar mas informacion a la tabla y por lo tanto al hacer el select obtener una columna mas al resultado

Comment: SQL SERVER 2014

Comment: Entonces creo que necesitas usar SQL dinámico para resolver este problema. Eso sí, no veo que necesites cursores para esto. Estoy curioso de ver si Lamak te propone algo ;)

Comment: @sstan pues tienes razón con lo de sql dinámico. Ahora, el problema de mi propuesta es que no tengo datos para poder probar el código...y con SQL dinámico siempre surge alguna complicación

Comment: @Lamak: Al menos la idea de la respuesta se ve bien. Lo que me tenías curioso es cuando preguntastes por la versión de SQL Server. ¿Hay alguna mejora en una versión más reciente que permitiría hacer este tipo de consulta sin SQL dinámico?

Comment: @sstan pues no jeje. Pregunté porque inicialmente pensaba en usar `ROW_NUMBER`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varios problemas con tu consulta actual. Primero que todo, SQL trabaja en sets, por lo que esa forma de escribir el código debería ser preferible a usar cursores (por eficiencia). Ahora, hay veces donde un cursor es lo mejor, pero este no es el caso en tu código.

Por otro lado, por favor trata de usar joins explícitos. Los joins implícitos como los que estás usando están deprecados hace más de 20 años.

Finalmente, vas a tener que usar un `PIVOT` dinámico como intuyó @sstan. El código debería ser algo similar a:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'', @cols NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @cols += STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(mod_Id)
                       FROM dbo.Models
                       GROUP BY Modelos
                       FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '');

SET @sql = N'SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT b.brn_Name, m.mod_Id
        FROM dbo.BRANCHES b
        INNER JOIN dbo.BrnHasMac bm
            ON b.brn_Id = bm.brn_Id
        INNER JOIN dbo.MACHINES m 
            ON m.mac_Id = bm.mac_Id
  ) AS d
  PIVOT (COUNT([mod_Id]) FOR [mod_Id] IN (' + @cols + ')) AS p;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Gracias, esta era la respuesta que necesitaba
Si funciona como debe ser
Voy a analizar el codigo para entender bien como es que trabaja (Estoy empezando en SQL)

Comment: Y como haría en el caso de querer mostrar resultados de 2 tablas, por ejemplo tengo "ingresos y egresos", ambas tablas tienen los mismos campos, con los mismos nombres y orden, comparten un campo llamado tabla la cual es "I o E" segun Ingresos y Egresos, necesito listar los resultados de ambas tablas pero que se muestre el campo tabla segun corresponda, intenté con UNION pero lo que hace es unirlos laterales, necesito que los resultados se unan por filas y no por columnas.